# What is meant by clones of B-cells?

Tags: immunology

I was reading Cellular and Molecular Immunology
By Abul K. Abbas, Andrew H. H. Lichtman, Shiv Pillai and stumbled upon the following excerpt $-$

> In every individual there are millions of different clones of B-cells,each producing antibody molecules with the same antigen binding site and different in this site from the antibodies produced by other clones.

What are these clones of B-cells, one producing monoclonal antibodies and the other polyclonal antibodies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you read further you'll get it. Basically, when the antibody expressed on a B-cell recognizes an antigen, then the B-cell divides and expands its population to produce more antibodies (through plasma cells). This process is called clonal expansion.

Comment: This is correct, but a very short summary of a very complex (and cool) process. To expand a bit: After T-cell dependant B-cell activation through an antigen to the B-cell receptor, the B-cell divides into a few very short-lived plasma cells and centroblasts. The latter undergo somatic hypermutation and rapid cell expansion to result in many different B-cells which produce similar, but different antibodies). With the help of follicular T-cells, only centroblast with the antibody with the highest affinity to the antigene survives and this one undergoes clonal expansion.

Comment: @Narusan you are right. I kept the answer very simple because the OP was a beginner in this topic. Also, the reference is the same book (mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 2):

Cytokines which are produced by effector T4-helper lymphocytes helps activated B-lymphocytes to proliferate and produce clones.

So, even if limited  B-lymphocytes may have an antibody molecule able to bind particular epitope, still many cells are produced with the this specificity. This is clonal expansion (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OlfJ.jpg)

Link for this answer 
https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Microbiology/Book%3A_Microbiology_(Kaiser)/Unit_6%3A_Adaptive_Immunity/13%3A_Humoral_Immunity/13.1%3A_Antibodies_(Immunoglobulins)/13.1E%3A_Clonal_Selection_and_Clonal_Expansion

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Your answer sounds reasonable, however, it is likely to receive a more favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best, but a textbook available online would seem sufficient for this question). At a minimum, please edit your answer to include the source for the figure. ——— You may also benefit from taking the [tour] and then consulting the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Hi Twinkle. If I may offer some advice; please familiarize yourself with formatting. Secondly, and more importantly, please do not answer questions from 4 years ago that are adequately answered. You have been filling the front page with old material that is well suited for the archive!

Comment: Ok will follow your advice

Comment: @SPr — You may be correct in suggesting the contributor improves his formatting, although you give no indication of where he is deficient. However I do not accept that the age of the question is relevant if the contributor has something new. I do not regard a three sentence answer as "adequate", and this answer covers a different aspect from WYSIWYG. I would say the problem with this answer is that it does not explain things clearly enough. Of course this is such a basic question covered in text books that perhaps the question should be whether to answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

B cells are a type of cells that produce antibodies. Each B cell produces a different type of antibody. For example, consider the following B cells: C1, C2, and C3, which produce antibodies A1, A2, and A3, respectively. We are dealing with 3 B cell **clones**, given that they produce 3 different types of antibodies.

Let's say that the B cell C1 happens to produce antibodies (A1) that are specific against the lipopolysaccharide (LPS) of a certain bacteria. When this bacteria enters the body, C1 will detect its presence and become activated. Two things happen when a B cell becomes activated: (1) differentiation, and (2) proliferation. Therefore, from the B cell clone C1 many more B cells will be produced through cell division, and all of these cells will produce antibodies A1 with the same affinity towards LPS. This would be a **monoclonal antibody response**, given that only antibodies from one B cell clone are produced.

If B cell C2 also produces antibodies (A2) with affinity for LPS, then upon bacterial infection C2 would become activated, proliferate, and differentiate. Given that antibodies (A1 and A2) from two different B cell clones (C1 and C2) are produced, this is a **polyclonal antibody response**.

Hope this helps!